# MVVM Light Resharper Templates?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper, mvvm-light

Since mvvm-light's C# snippets will not show if I'm using resharper, and my google skills have failed me... Does anyone know where i can get a set of MVVM light specific templates for ReSharper?  I've found a post from Laurent that says he's working on it, but I've not been able to find them, and the thought of building them all myself seems daunting.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using MVVM Light and ReSharper. The snippets show up when I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>.

Answer (score 2):

simply type the shortcut of a snippet (for example: mvvminpc ) somewhere in your source code and press <kbd>TAB</kbd> <kbd>TAB</kbd>

Please make sure that the snippets are available and correctly installed. You could use the Visual Studio Code Snippet Manager (Tools -> Code Snippet Manager) for this purpose. Select the Language (eg. C# ) an then you should see a folder named MvvmLightCSharpSnippets which contains all MVVM Light Snippets.

[image: Screenshot: Code Snippet Manager]